# Unattended streaming service

Tags: web-services, streaming

I have a dashboard of a machine in a computer that I want to stream it to a server in the internet that allows people to view it via web browser in real-time but also check for past videos.

Theoretically, the dashboard runs all day long from 6 to 22h. I was wondering if there is a streaming service (free or paid) that keeps listening during the night to the software in the client (tightVNC, OBS or whatever) to unattendedly connect at 6 a.m. when the client starts up again. This way, every morning client and server should handshake and start automatically the streaming service without human intervention. It's that possible?

Best regards.